# CMake Error for depending two custom packages

Tags: ros, cmake, dependencies

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have created a package called agv_msgs. I want to make this package contain my custom messages. I have built it with no problems. After that I have created another packege called agv_teleop and while creating this package I indicated agv_msgs, std_msgs, roscpp and rospy as its dependencies. I have modified the CMake list but when I try to catkin_make them I get the following error;

```
CMake Error at /home/emreay/catkin_ws/devel/share/agv_msgs/cmake/agv_msgsConfig.cmake:141 (message):
  Project 'agv_teleop' tried to find library 'agv_msgs'.  The library is
  neither a target nor built/installed properly.  Did you compile project
  'agv_msgs'? Did you find_package() it before the subdirectory containing
  its code is included?
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/ros/groovy/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:75 (find_package)
  agv_teleop/CMakeLists.txt:7 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
make: *** [cmake_check_build_system] Error 1
Invoking "make cmake_check_build_system" failed
```

I have done the catkin_make for agv_msgs before I create the agv_teleop package. I also included agv_teleop for find_package() in CMakeLists of agv_teleop. I cannot figure out what I was doing wrong.

My CMakeLists for agv_msgs;

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(agv_msgs)

## Find catkin macros and libraries
## if COMPONENTS list like find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS xyz)
## is used, also find other catkin packages
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  roscpp
  rospy
  std_msgs
  message_generation
)

## System dependencies are found with CMake's conventions
# find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS system)


## Uncomment this if the package has a setup.py. This macro ensures
## modules and global scripts declared therein get installed
## See http://ros.org/doc/api/catkin/html/user_guide/setup_dot_py.html
# catkin_python_setup()

################################################
## Declare ROS messages, services and actions ##
################################################

## To declare and build messages, services or actions from within this
## package, follow these steps:
## * Let MSG_DEP_SET be the set of packages whose message types you use in
##   your messages/services/actions (e.g. std_msgs, actionlib_msgs, ...).
## * In the file package.xml:
##   * add a build_depend and a run_depend tag for each package in MSG_DEP_SET
##   * If MSG_DEP_SET isn't empty the following dependencies might have been
##     pulled in transitively but can be declared for certainty nonetheless:
##     * add a build_depend tag for "message_generation"
##     * add a run_depend tag for "message_runtime"
## * In this file (CMakeLists.txt):
##   * add "message_generation" and every package in MSG_DEP_SET to
##     find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS ...)
##   * add "message_runtime" and every package in MSG_DEP_SET to
##     catkin_package(CATKIN_DEPENDS ...)
##   * uncomment the add_*_files sections below as needed
##     and list every .msg/.srv/.action file to be processed
##   * uncomment the generate_messages entry below
##   * add every package in MSG_DEP_SET to generate_messages(DEPENDENCIES ...)

## Generate messages in the 'msg' folder
 add_message_files(
   FILES
   uint8Array.msg
 )

## Generate services in the 'srv' folder
# add_service_files(
#   FILES
#   Service1.srv
#   Service2.srv
# )

## Generate actions in the 'action' folder
# add_action_files(
#   FILES
#   Action1.action
#   Action2.action
# )

## Generate added messages and services with any dependencies listed here
 generate_messages(
   DEPENDENCIES
   std_msgs
 )

###################################
## catkin specific configuration ##
###################################
## The catkin_package macro generates cmake config files for your package
## Declare things to be passed to dependent projects
## INCLUDE_DIRS: uncomment this if you package contains header files
## LIBRARIES: libraries you create in this project that dependent projects also need
## CATKIN_DEPENDS: catkin_packages dependent projects also need
## DEPENDS: system dependencies of this project that dependent projects also need
catkin_package(
  INCLUDE_DIRS include
  LIBRARIES agv_msgs
  CATKIN_DEPENDS roscpp rospy std_msgs
  DEPENDS system_lib
)

###########
## Build ##
###########

## Specify additional locations of header files
## Your package locations should be listed before other locations
# include_directories(include)
include_directories(
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

## Declare a cpp library
# add_library(agv_msgs
#   src/${PROJECT_NAME}/agv_msgs.cpp
# )

## Declare a cpp executable
# add_executable(agv_msgs_node src/agv_msgs_node.cpp)

## Add cmake target dependencies of the executable/library
## as an example, message headers may need to be generated before nodes
# add_dependencies(agv_msgs_node agv_msgs_generate_messages_cpp)

## Specify libraries to link a library or executable target against
# target_link_libraries(agv_msgs_node
#   ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
# )

#############
## Install ##
#############

# all install targets should use catkin DESTINATION variables
# See http://ros.org/doc/api/catkin/html/adv_user_guide/variables.html

## Mark executable scripts (Python etc.) for installation
## in contrast to setup.py, you can choose the destination
# install(PROGRAMS
#   scripts/my_python_script
#   DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION}
# )

## Mark executables and/or libraries for installation
# install(TARGETS agv_msgs agv_msgs_node
#   ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
#   LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
#   RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION}
# )

## Mark cpp header files for installation
# install(DIRECTORY include/${PROJECT_NAME}/
#   DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_INCLUDE_DESTINATION}
#   FILES_MATCHING PATTERN "*.h"
#   PATTERN ".svn" EXCLUDE
# )

## Mark other files for installation (e.g. launch and bag files, etc.)
# install(FILES
#   # myfile1
#   # myfile2
#   DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_SHARE_DESTINATION}
# )

#############
## Testing ##
#############

## Add gtest based cpp test target and link libraries
# catkin_add_gtest(${PROJECT_NAME}-test test/test_agv_msgs.cpp)
# if(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME}-test)
#   target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}-test ${PROJECT_NAME})
# endif()

## Add folders to be run by python nosetests
# catkin_add_nosetests(test)
```

My CMakeLists for agv_teleop;

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(agv_teleop)

## Find catkin macros and libraries
## if COMPONENTS list like find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS xyz)
## is used, also find other catkin packages
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  agv_msgs
  ps3joy
  roscpp
  rospy
  std_msgs
  message_generation
  tf
)

## System dependencies are found with CMake's conventions
## find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS system)


## Uncomment this if the package has a setup.py. This macro ensures
## modules and global scripts declared therein get installed
## See http://ros.org/doc/api/catkin/html/user_guide/setup_dot_py.html
# catkin_python_setup()

################################################
## Declare ROS messages, services and actions ##
################################################

## To declare and build messages, services or actions from within this
## package, follow these steps:
## * Let MSG_DEP_SET be the set of packages whose message types you use in
##   your messages/services/actions (e.g. std_msgs, actionlib_msgs, ...).
## * In the file package.xml:
##   * add a build_depend and a run_depend tag for each package in MSG_DEP_SET
##   * If MSG_DEP_SET isn't empty the following dependencies might have been
##     pulled in transitively but can be declared for certainty nonetheless:
##     * add a build_depend tag for "message_generation"
##     * add a run_depend tag for "message_runtime"
## * In this file (CMakeLists.txt):
##   * add "message_generation" and every package in MSG_DEP_SET to
##     find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS ...)
##   * add "message_runtime" and every package in MSG_DEP_SET to
##     catkin_package(CATKIN_DEPENDS ...)
##   * uncomment the add_*_files sections below as needed
##     and list every .msg/.srv/.action file to be processed
##   * uncomment the generate_messages entry below
##   * add every package in MSG_DEP_SET to generate_messages(DEPENDENCIES ...)

## Generate messages in the 'msg' folder
# add_message_files(
#   FILES
#   Message1.msg
#   Message2.msg
# )

## Generate services in the 'srv' folder
# add_service_files(
#   FILES
#   Service1.srv
#   Service2.srv
# )

## Generate actions in the 'action' folder
# add_action_files(
#   FILES
#   Action1.action
#   Action2.action
# )

## Generate added messages and services with any dependencies listed here
 generate_messages(
   DEPENDENCIES
   agv_msgs
   std_msgs
 )

###################################
## catkin specific configuration ##
###################################
## The catkin_package macro generates cmake config files for your package
## Declare things to be passed to dependent projects
## INCLUDE_DIRS: uncomment this if you package contains header files
## LIBRARIES: libraries you create in this project that dependent projects also need
## CATKIN_DEPENDS: catkin_packages dependent projects also need
## DEPENDS: system dependencies of this project that dependent projects also need
catkin_package(
  INCLUDE_DIRS include
  LIBRARIES agv_teleop
  CATKIN_DEPENDS agv_msgs ps3joy roscpp rospy std_msgs
  DEPENDS system_lib
)

###########
## Build ##
###########

## Specify additional locations of header files
## Your package locations should be listed before other locations
# include_directories(include)
include_directories(
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  /home/emreay/catkin_ws/src/agv_msgs
)

## Declare a cpp library
# add_library(agv_teleop
#   src/${PROJECT_NAME}/agv_teleop.cpp
# )

## Declare a cpp executable
# add_executable(agv_teleop_node src/agv_teleop_node.cpp)

## Add cmake target dependencies of the executable/library
## as an example, message headers may need to be generated before nodes
# add_dependencies(agv_teleop_node agv_teleop_generate_messages_cpp)

## Specify libraries to link a library or executable target against
# target_link_libraries(agv_teleop_node
#   ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
# )

#############
## Install ##
#############

# all install targets should use catkin DESTINATION variables
# See http://ros.org/doc/api/catkin/html/adv_user_guide/variables.html

## Mark executable scripts (Python etc.) for installation
## in contrast to setup.py, you can choose the destination
# install(PROGRAMS
#   scripts/my_python_script
#   DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION}
# )

## Mark executables and/or libraries for installation
# install(TARGETS agv_teleop agv_teleop_node
#   ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
#   LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
#   RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION}
# )

## Mark cpp header files for installation
# install(DIRECTORY include/${PROJECT_NAME}/
#   DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_INCLUDE_DESTINATION}
#   FILES_MATCHING PATTERN "*.h"
#   PATTERN ".svn" EXCLUDE
# )

## Mark other files for installation (e.g. launch and bag files, etc.)
# install(FILES
#   # myfile1
#   # myfile2
#   DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_SHARE_DESTINATION}
# )

#############
## Testing ##
#############

## Add gtest based cpp test target and link libraries
# catkin_add_gtest(${PROJECT_NAME}-test test/test_agv_teleop.cpp)
# if(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME}-test)
#   target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}-test ${PROJECT_NAME})
# endif()

## Add folders to be run by python nosetests
# catkin_add_nosetests(test)

add_executable(teleop src/teleop.cpp)
target_link_libraries(teleop ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
add_dependencies(teleop agv_gencpp)
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/210301/cmake-error-for-depending-two-custom-packages/) by [emreay](https://answers.ros.org/users/12731/emreay/) on ROS Answers with karma: 90 on 2015-06-01

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2015-06-01**:
Please post the CMake code of the `agv_msgs` package. It seems like you are exporting a library there which does not exist.

**Comment by [emreay](https://answers.ros.org/users/12731/emreay/) on 2015-06-02**:
Thank you, I have revised my question and added CMake code of `agv_msgs`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Comment the following lines in the `catkin_package` calls:

```
  LIBRARIES agv_msgs
```

and

```
   LIBRARIES agv_teleop
```

They are only required if you create a lib using `add_library`, which you don't...

---

Originally posted by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) with karma: 7555 on 2015-06-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3